# Learning class in python but having issue that probably is simple

Tags: python, class

I have simple code that creates a rectangle

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
        self.corner = posn
        self.width = w
        self.height = h

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.corner, self.width, self.height)

box = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), 100, 200)
print("box: ", box)
```

The output of this code is

```
('box: ', <__main__.Rectangle instance at 0x0000000002368108>)
```

I expect the output to be

```
box: ((0, 0), 100, 200)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) post on `repr` vs `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `__repr__` in both the Classes, like this

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
        self.corner = posn
        self.width = w
        self.height = h

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.corner, self.width, self.height)

print "box: ", box
# box:  ((0, 0),100,200)
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy response.

Answer (score 4):

You don't define a `__repr__()` on your `Rectangle` class. Printing a tuple (as you are doing) uses the `repr()` of the class, not the `str()`. You also need a `__str__()` on your `Point` class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using Python 2.x: In Python 2.x, [`print` is statement, not a function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement).

By putting `(...)`, you're printing `str(("box:", box))`. (A tuple containing a string and `Rectangle` object)

Remove parentheses, and define `Point.__str__` to get what you expected.

---

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.x, self.y))
        # OR   return '({0.x}, {0.y})'.format(self)

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
        self.corner = posn
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.corner, self.width, self.height)

box = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), 100, 200)
print("box: ", box)  # This prints a tuple: `str(("box: ", box))`
print "box: ", box   # This prints `box: ` and `str(box)`.
```

output:

```
('box: ', <__main__.Rectangle instance at 0x00000000027BC888>)
box:  ((0, 0),100,200)
```

Comment: @AirThomas, If OP is using Python 3.x or using `from __future__ import print_function`, there should be no surrounding parentheses.

Comment: @AirThomas that print does not throw an exception on 2.x

Comment: @AirThomas, `print` statement does not complain about parentheses. Parentheses are interpreted as a part of an expression.

Comment: I am using Python scripter
Version 2.5.3.0 x64